# Set width to 100% if height is less than X%

Tags: css, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using ionic to build a mobile app, and have a use case where I have a video of unknown dimension (the plugin I use doesn't allow me to get the height and width). It can be a vertical or horizontal video. If it's a vertical (i.e. height might be greater than the mobile height), I want to resize it e.g. set max-height: 70%, nevermind if there are spaces on the side; If it's a horizontal (i.e. height will never be greater than mobile height), I want to resize it to full width e.g. set width: 100%.

The problem is that I can't apply classes depending on whether it is a vertical or horizontal video because I can't determine the height and width. Is there any pure css method to accomplish this use case?

Comment: Really some code of your html is needed. Only thing I can say now is try to get the element of your div with an id and do `console.log( document.getElementsByClassName('your-video-id-in-html') );`

Comment: _“Is there any pure css method to accomplish this use case?”_ - no ... CSS has even less knowledge of what the actual video dimensions might be, than you do ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `max-height` on the container with inheriting it on the 'video' element.

See the example, i've implemented it with image, but it should be the same with video element.

```css
.container-fitter {
  display: inline-block;
  max-height: 150px;
}

.container-fitter img {
  height: auto;
  max-height: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fitter">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" />
</div>

<div class="container-fitter">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x350" />
</div>
```